# Jquery event trickling

Tags: jquery, events

Is there any way I can make a jquery event trickle down the DOM as well as bubbling up?

I'm trying to implement a 'create' event that's triggered when a node is added to the dom. I've found a few implementations, but all have one thing in common and that's that the root of the inserted element fires a create event, but none of it's children. If the use case is to give a node a  "constructor" function, then the create event needs to apply to all the new nodes doesn't it?

For example, if I insert an unordered list with a few list items in it. With all methods I've found the ul create event will fire, but none of the li's.

My best idea is to somehow bind the trickle phase of the event so the event starts at the ul, them trickles into all the li's.

As the rest of the system is using jquery events, I would like to keep it that way, but a pure js solution would work too.

I'm also only really concerned with webkit right now, so any solution doesn't have to be IE safe.

Thanks

@Dave:

Someone correct me if I'm wrong here, but as I understand it: all events (except a few in IE) first "bubble" up your dom tree; so from li to ul to body, then turn around and "trickle" back down; from body to ul to the li that was clicked and onto any of the li's children.

You can listen for events that are "trickling" by setting the third param of addEventListener to true in most browsers (I don't think IE's attachEvent has the option though).

We have both bubbling and trickling mostly because there was some confusion about how it should be done back when the Internet was born, and the w3c just adopted both in it's specs to keep everybody happy and backwards compatibility good. Over time trickling has been kind of phased out because it's pretty useless in most cases, which is why I don't think jquery has any option for it. It seems to me that a "create" event is one of those odd cases where trickling would be useful. The trick would be how to integrate the firing of a create event and then making it trickle into jquery in such a way that we keep browser compatibility and the bind()/trigger() jquery API we like...

Comment: How do you listen to such an event? what element are you binding the event to?

Comment: Sorry Dave, got a little long winded in my response and it wouldn't let me put it in a comment. See my edit above.

Comment: I’m still confused. By "trickling" you mean capturing, right? But I don’t see how this will work differently for your custom event. If the inserted elements most inner child would be the event target, it would be accessible when listening for it at the descendant element as long as it bubbles. Capturing/bubbling is more like a "callback order", and has nothing to do with the direction based on the event target.

Comment: also "from body to ul to the li that was clicked and onto any of the li's children." - this is not the case. It stops at the event target (li) in the capturing phase, before bubbling up.

Answer (score 3):

I’m going to post an answer here instead of discussing in the comments.

First of all, no events travel below the event target. According to w3c, the event has three phases: **capturing**, **at target** and **bubbling**. So if someone clicks an UL, the event goes:

```
BODY > DIV > UL (capturing)
UL (at target)
UL > DIV > BODY (bubbling)
```

(it also goes beyond body). Worth noting here is that this is *regardless of what element bound the event*. You could bind a click event to the DIV, and the event would travel the same way. The event target is not necessarily the element that bound the event (that is the currentTarget).

Both capturing and bubbling phase moves through the same set of elements, only in *two different directions*. So you can see it more like a callback order.

If you bind a callback to an event with the capturing flag set to "true", it just means that this callback will be executed before any other event callbacks in the bubble.

So, if your "special" event triggers when inserting DOM content, you could:

1. Make sure the event bubbles
2. Make the most inner element of the inserted DOM the event target

That way, you can listen to the event from the container element and still make sure all elements in the inserted DOM is a part of the bubble.

Answer (score 0):

jquery delegate will do the trick.  events are bound to all current and future child nodes.

example:

```
$('ul').delegate('li','click',function(){alert("I've been clicked!");});
```

Comment: Delegate, and live/die, bind elements to the body tag (or some context if given, either way a parent node), so only register events bubbling up the dom. So even if I can make a "create" event, which jquery doesn't understand by default, it's going the wrong way. I want the create event to trickle down the dom, not bubble up it.